# How to trigger a dbms_scheduler job with SimpleJdbcCall in Spring boot?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, scheduler

I'm trying to invoke a job from my Spring Boot service where I'm using JDBCTemplate to run Selected queries on the DB. I use `SimpleJdbcCall`:

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(template);
    simpleJdbcCall
          .withCatalogName("dbms_scheduler")
          .withProcedureName("run_job")
          .execute(new MapSqlParameterSource("JOB_NAME","My_Job_Name"));

}
```

but I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB()}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'RUN_JOB' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

i tried to use `.withSchemaName`  instead of `withCatalogName` but I receive the same error.

Would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: The [`RUN_JOB`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72395) procedure takes two parameters. Besides the job name, there is also `use_current_session`. This defaults to `TRUE`, therefore I'm not sure if it causes the problem.

Comment: thank you @wolφi for the answer. even with `use_current_session` I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with `CallableStatement` using this code:

```
String sql = "{call DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(?)}";

      try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection(); 

              CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);) {

                 //Set IN parameter
                 stmt.setString(1, "CTI_QUEUEHANDLER");

                 //Execute stored procedure
                 stmt.execute();

      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```